# Change a format of timestamp with perl

Tags: perl, time

I have a timestamps in my data. which looks like this:

```
2020-04-10 14:11:18
```

```
2020-04-30 16:47:21
```

It is a string. How could i change their formats, so they look like this:

```
Apr 10 14:11:18
```

```
Apr 30 16:47:21
```

What library should i use? Maybe DateTime?

Comment: What have you tried? What problems are you having? Please show us your code.

Answer (score 3):

No module/library necessary, a simple hash with months names can assists in transforming date to desired format.

> Separate date and time with `split ' ', $timestamp`
>
> Separate date into components with `split '-', $date`
>
> Get month name from hash with `$months{$month+0}`
>
> Form new date string in desired format

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';


my $timestamp = '2020-04-10 14:11:18';

my $date = transform($timestamp);

say $date;


sub transform {
    my $timestamp = shift;

    my %months = ( 1 => 'Jan',  2 => 'Feb',  3 => 'Mar',  4 => 'Apr',
                   5 => 'May',  6 => 'Jun',  7 => 'Jul',  8 => 'Aug',
                   9 => 'Sep', 10 => 'Oct', 11 => 'Nov', 12 => 'Dec'
                );

    my($date,$time) = split ' ', $timestamp;
    my($year,$month,$day) = split '-', $date;
    
    return "$months{$month+0} $day $time";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

DateTime would certainly work here, but [Time::Piece](https://metacpan.org/pod/Time::Piece) has been part of the standard Perl library since 2007. It has a `strptime()` ("string parse time") method to create objects from a string and a `strftime()` ("string format time") method to produce formatted date strings from your objects.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';
use Time::Piece;

while (<DATA>) {
  chomp;
  my $date = Time::Piece->strptime($_, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S');

  say $date->strftime('%b %d %H:%M:%S');
}

__DATA__
2020-04-10 14:11:18
2020-04-30 16:47:21
```

Comment: An additional note: The `%b` conversion of `strftime` is locale-dependent. This could be good or a problem, depending on the intended use of the result.

Answer (score 0):

Above both solutions are good. Below code is to depict one more simple way to format date.

DateTime::Format::Strptime - Parse and format strp and strf time patterns

%F : Equivalent to %Y-%m-%d. (This is the ISO style date)

%T : Equivalent to %H:%M:%S.

%b or %B or %h : The month name according to the given locale, in abbreviated form or the full name.

```
use DateTime::Format::Strptime;

my $current_date_format="%F %T";
my $new_date_format="%b %d %T";

my $date_time = "2020-04-10 14:11:18";

my $formatter = DateTime::Format::Strptime->new(pattern => "$current_date_format");
my $dt_obj    = $formatter->parse_datetime($date_time);
my $datetime  = $dt_obj->strftime($new_date_format);

print "\n New format Datetime: $datetime \n";
```

Output:

```
New format Datetime: Apr 10 14:11:18
```

Ref:

- https://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime::Format::Strptime
- https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1179258